# Python - running a file listener when system boot till system switched off to do some automated actions, but not working

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have to read a file forever such as when system boot and till end. Based on the file events python script has to take actions. But its weired that my python script is not doing so.

Step 1:  crontab and on boot i have this following

```
tail -f /var/tmp/event.log | python /var/tmp/event.py &
```

Step 2: other applications are now dumping lines in the file /var/tmp/event.log, for example

```
java -cp Java.jar Main.main | tee -a /var/tmp/event.log

or

echo "tst" >> /var/tmp/event.log

or

otherapps | tee -a /var/tmp/event.log
```

Step 3: python event.py is having a loop to listen the commands and execute but those execution is not happening

```
import sys, time, os
while True:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if line:
    if "runme.sh" in line:
      os.system("/var/tmp/runme.sh")
    if "killfirefox.sh" in line:
      os.system("/var/tmp/killfirefox.sh")
    if "shotemail.sh" in line:
      os.system("/var/tmp/shotemail.sh")
    if "scan.sh" in line:
      os.system("/var/tmp/scan.sh")
    if "screenshot.sh" in line:
      os.system("/var/tmp/screenshot.sh")

  else:
    time.sleep(1)
```

What is that i am doing wrong? I have verified the event.log file is having correct command per line and even manually when i do `echo "runme.sh" | python /var/tmp/event.py` it also works but why not working while using boot time/crontab mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the tail command's output is being buffered.  When you write to a pipe in bash, the output is not immediately sent to the other command - it is buffered and then output later.  For an example, try running `ls -l | more` on a large directory.  You'll see a noticeable delay before `more` outputs the listing.

There are a number of ways around this.  You could use `stdbuf` (see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) for more on it) like so:

`stdbuf -i0 -e0 -o0 tail -f /var/tmp/event.log | python /var/tmp/event.py`

Try this and see if it works better.  A more elegant solution would be to use a temporary file that only gets written to when there is output to be read, which is then monitored by the python script, or a [named pipe](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156).